# checkbox respond slowly on IE11

Tags: html, performance, checkbox, internet-explorer-11

i have more than 100 checkboxes on a page. when checkbox is clicked, check-mark appear after seconds delay.
it  works fine on chrome but problem is only found on Internet Explorer. 
remove all css and click event wont solve the problem. its seems like default behavior of IE.
one interesting fact, if around 50 checkboxes appear on screen, problem goes away. no slowness is observed if checkboxes are not in hundreds.
Please suggest.

Comment: would lazy loading the checkboxes be a workaround

Comment: Maybe you need a redesign. No user can cope with 100+ checkboxes. Split them on different pages in logical groupings.

Comment: but chrome is working perfectly for same functionality. is it IE limitation? i found microsoft blogs for the year 2014 where users shared same problem but unfortunately no resolution was found even on that forum.Link of forum is https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/e89fef0a-22a6-4e9b-b03a-957fe47c2459/ie-11-checkbox-delay-bug?forum=iewebdevelopment